# Where do I save my Haskell "modules"?

Tags: windows, function, haskell, module

I put some functions in a file. Where on my PC should I save this file so that I can easily load my functions?

I am using the Haskell Platform on a Windows 64-bit computer.

Comment: In the cloud ... </another bad joke>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I usually put my modules in the same directory tree, and start up `ghci` at the root directory of the tree.  Then modules can import each other, and I can easily `:load` modules into `ghci` interactively.

```
$ ghci

.... loading ....

Prelude> :load directory/subdirectory/mymodule.hs
```

Comment: My `ghci` is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2011.2.0.0\bin`. Do I put them in here?

Comment: No!  When it installed, it should have put itself into the path or an environmental variable, so that you can run `ghci` from the command line, no matter which directory you're in.  If the environment variables aren't set up correctly, you can change them manually through the control panel.

Comment: Wait... what? What is that you have your functions in on your PC?

Comment: @perl.j -- I create some directory, anywhere I want, maybe in MyDocuments.  I put all my Haskell stuff in there, including modules that have functions (for great good!).  Then, I open up the shell, move to that directory, and type `ghci`.  Windows knows where to find `ghci` for me, even though it's in a different directory, as you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your modules to be accessible from a few different projects, I'd recommend to create a cabal package for them and install it using `cabal install`. Publishing to hackage is not required - `cabal install` without arguments looks for `.cabal` file in the current directory and installs the corresponding package.

If you want your modules to be accessible from a single project - the usual practice of organizing your sources in a hierarchical folder tree applies to Haskell as well. Let me show an example:

```
Hello/World.hs
Foo/Bar.hs
Quux.hs
Hello.hs
```

`Hello/World.hs` should have `module Hello.World where` in the header. The main module should have  `module Main`, but actual file name can be anything (e.g. `Quux.hs`). In `Foo/Bar.hs` you can use `import Hello.World`. When you load `Foo/Bar.hs` in `ghci`, the current directory should be the root of your tree, or else it will not find Hello.World. You can pass module names instead of file names to ghci: e.g. ghci Hello.World will work.

Here are the documentation:

http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/separate-compilation.html

http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/packages.html

Comment: +1 for this.  Cabal is actually very easy to use now; for this use-case it's pretty much entirely automatic (`cabal init` produces a `.cabal` file for you, and you just need to fill in the build dependencies)